# How do backups work in DirectAdmin?

Tags: backup, directadmin

I'm sure there's a good amount of developers here that use DirectAdmin and I had a quick question.

I've always used cPanel and I'm not on a server that is using DirectAdmin instead.  Where in DirectAdmin can you generate a full backup of the account at the user level?

Also, do DirectAdmin backups include everything related to the account like cPanel backups do?  For example, not only the files and databases but also the cron jobs, DNS zones, email accounts, etc.?

And where are the backups stored by default?  Is there an option to send the backups to a remote server via FTP like you can with cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different backup systems built into DA:

1. Admin Tools | System Backup. This tool lets you backup configuration data and arbitrary directories, locally or using FTP or SCP.
2. Admin Tools | Admin Backup/Transfer. This tool is oriented toward backing up data account by account, in one archive per account, in a format that you can use to restore from (in the same tool) on the original or another DA server (i.e. if you want to transfer to a new server). You can back up locally and/or via FTP.

Both options can also be scheduled via cron.

Depending on your level of access, only one of these might be available to you. This page has further info for non-administrators: http://www.site-helper.com/backup.html.

Answer (score -1):

You can improve your DirectAdmin backup with an incremental backup plugin that includes local and remote backup location, please check the setup guide [here](https://github.com/ModMasterPro/DirectAdmin-Backup-Manager)

Comment: Hello ModMaster. Welcome to StackOverflow. Jack seemed to be asking not about improving his DirectAdmin backup, but where the backups are stored and whether he can "send the backups to a remote server via FTP like you can with cPanel".